# Flash architecture - detecting loading status of multiple external MP3s

Tags: flash, oop, audio

I'm loading a number of MP3 files into my Flash (the number changes dynamically).

I would like to be able to say, in total, how much longer all the files will take to load.

I can do this for each individual sound

Mp3.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, test_function);

But each sound is loaded by an instance of my sound loader class, how can I pass the ProgressEvent up to the parent object, and then have it calculate the total time to load?

Thanks,

Jimmy.

Answer (score 0):

not quiet sure about if it works (less code information from your side), but qhat about adding a class which holds all information from each mp3 loader?!

The ProgressEvent gives you the current bytesLoaded and the bytesTotal in Numbers.

So your MP3LoaderDataClass class should have a reference to each MP3 Loader with bytesLoaded and bytesTotal.

- it also should have a getLoadedCompleteStatus function which returns the counts of all bytesLoaded and all bytesTotal in Numbers
- it should be listening to all your PrgressEvent and should be updated every time (sth like an update function with id/target name from your loader which is called in your test_function)
- it should also throw an event if it was updated, which you can use in your window which shows user your load Complete status

I didn t try sth like that yet, but I would try this way.. hope it helps,
kris

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I have tried this, the problem is I don't seem to be able to access the properties of the child objects
SoundObject.bytesLeft (with var bytesLeft declared in the SoundObject class) doesn't work